# Optimization DB2 query with mass join

Tags: sql, database, db2, query-optimization

I have complex query:

```
select rma.RELATION_MANAGER_ID,
       rm.ORG_STRUCTURE_ID,
       rm.RELATIONSHIP_MANAGER_NM,
       count(distinct ppa.PARTY_ID) as count_party
from RELATIONSHIP_MANAGER rm --15808 row
join RELATIONSHIP_MANAGER_MARKET rmm --1560 row
   on rm.RELATIONSHIP_MANAGER_ID = rmm.RELATIONSHIP_MANAGER_ID
      and rmm.INCLUDE_IN_REPORT = 'Y'
join MARKET_SEGMENT rm_ms --4 row
   on rmm.MARKET_SEGMENT_ID = rm_ms.MARKET_SEGMENT_ID
      and rm_ms.MARKET_SEGMENT = '01'
join RELATIONSHIP_MANAGER_ALLOCATION rma --61349 row
   on rm.RELATIONSHIP_MANAGER_ID = rma.RELATIONSHIP_MANAGER_ID
join CMD_PARTY_PORTFOLIO_ALLOCATION ppa --3114096 row
   on ppa.PORTFOLIO_ID = rma.PORTFOLIO_ID
join person ps --3112575 row
   on ps.IS_DELETED != 1 and ppa.party_id = ps.party_id
join PARTY p  --3114146 row
   on ppa.party_id=p.party_id
join MARKET_SEGMENT ms --4 row
   on  p.MARKET_SEGMENT_ID = ms.MARKET_SEGMENT_ID and ms.MARKET_SEGMENT = '01'
   where rm.IS_CM = 1 and rm.IS_DELETED != 1
group by rm.RELATIONSHIP_MANAGER_NM, rma.RELATIONSHIP_MANAGER_ID, rm.ORG_STRUCTURE_ID
```

Table columns have indexes:

```
rm.RELATIONSHIP_MANAGER_ID,
rmm.RELATIONSHIP_MANAGER_ID,
rmm.MARKET_SEGMENT_ID,
rm_ms.MARKET_SEGMENT_ID,
rma.RELATIONSHIP_MANAGER_ID,
ppa.PORTFOLIO_ID,
rma.PORTFOLIO_ID,
ppa.party_id,
ps.party_id,
p.party_id,
p.MARKET_SEGMENT_ID,
ms.MARKET_SEGMENT_ID
```

tables PARTY, PERSON have ~1-3 million row,
 runtime of query ~20second. I am comment

```
join MARKET_SEGMENT ms 
on  p.MARKET_SEGMENT_ID = ms.MARKET_SEGMENT_ID --and ms.MARKET_SEGMENT = '01'
```

runtime of query became ~3 second.
Explain why this is happening, please ?
Explain plan dont help me.. How i can optimization the query?

EDIT:
platform is DB2 for z/OS V9.7,
added size of table

EDIT2: explain plan shows that the first is always join the small size of the table

Comment: `MARKET_SEGMENT` does not have an index, and it's text.  If you have that comparison in your `On` clause, you will be performing that comparison for each `Join`.  Either put that condition in the `Where` clause or put an index on `MARKET_SEGMENT`.

Comment: when market_segment comparison with text, index dont work probably.

Comment: Optimization is platform dependent, if not version dependent as well. What platform is your DB2 server running on: IBM i, LUW, or z/OS?

Comment: i'm sorry, platform is z/OS 9.7

Comment: @Siyual - With `JOIN`s (that is, `INNER JOIN`s), there's no semantic difference between including a condition as part of the join criteria or in the `WHERE` clause; the optimizer is already moving conditions around (and reordering `JOIN`s!) as it sees fit.  The OP probably should add the column to an index, though, yes.  The fact that it's character-based (as opposed to any other type) is irrelevant for the condition chosen (a numeric type would (probably) have the same effect).

Comment: @debosh.andrey - Your query _may_ be able to be tweaked in some simple(ish) ways to run faster.  Try changing `rma.RELATIONSHIP_MANAGER_ID` to `rm.RELATIONSHIP_MANAGER_ID` (although the optimizer may be doing this automatically).  If there is an index on `RELATIONSHIP_MANAGER ` that starts with all three columns, put the `GROUP BY` references in that order.  For clarity's sake, always put the grouping columns in the same order in the `SELECT` clause.  You may be able to aggregate over a smaller collection of rows, but we need to know unique keys/a data sample.

Answer (score 0):

Just for grins, see if this makes any difference:

```
WITH
MktSeg( MARKET_SEGMENT_ID ) AS
( SELECT  MARKET_SEGMENT_ID
  FROM    MARKET_SEGMENT
  WHERE   MARKET_SEGMENT = '01' )
select rma.RELATION_MANAGER_ID,
       rm.ORG_STRUCTURE_ID,
       rm.RELATIONSHIP_MANAGER_NM,
       count(distinct ppa.PARTY_ID) as count_party
from RELATIONSHIP_MANAGER rm --15808 row
join RELATIONSHIP_MANAGER_MARKET rmm --1560 row
   on rm.RELATIONSHIP_MANAGER_ID = rmm.RELATIONSHIP_MANAGER_ID
      and rmm.INCLUDE_IN_REPORT = 'Y'
join MktSeg rm_ms --4 row
   on rmm.MARKET_SEGMENT_ID = rm_ms.MARKET_SEGMENT_ID
join RELATIONSHIP_MANAGER_ALLOCATION rma --61349 row
   on rm.RELATIONSHIP_MANAGER_ID = rma.RELATIONSHIP_MANAGER_ID
join CMD_PARTY_PORTFOLIO_ALLOCATION ppa --3114096 row
   on ppa.PORTFOLIO_ID = rma.PORTFOLIO_ID
join person ps --3112575 row
   on ps.IS_DELETED != 1 and ppa.party_id = ps.party_id
join PARTY p  --3114146 row
   on ppa.party_id=p.party_id
join MktSeg ms --4 row
   on  p.MARKET_SEGMENT_ID = ms.MARKET_SEGMENT_ID
WHERE rm.IS_CM = 1 AND rm.IS_DELETED != 1
group by rm.RELATIONSHIP_MANAGER_NM, rma.RELATIONSHIP_MANAGER_ID,
         rm.ORG_STRUCTURE_ID, rma.RELATION_MANAGER_ID
```

Note also that I've added an item to the Group By clause.

Comment: Runtime is the same. I note that the explain plan is too similar. I tried to rewrite the different designs, but the explain plan was not changed.